# Token is undefined when making a fetch request to login endpoint with React frontend and Express backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, express-jwt

I'm working on a web application using React for the frontend and Express for the backend. I'm trying to implement user authentication using JSON Web Tokens (JWT). However, I'm facing an issue where the token is undefined when making a fetch request to the login endpoint.

Here's the relevant part of my React frontend code:

```
import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { UserContext } from "../UserContext";

export default function LoginPage() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);
  const { setUserInfo } = useContext(UserContext);
  async function login(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch('https://personal-website-on6a.onrender.com/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      credentials: 'include',
      withCredentials: true,
    });
    if (response.ok) {
      response.json().then(userInfo => {
        setUserInfo(userInfo);
        setRedirect(true);
      });
    } else {
      alert('wrong credentials');
    }
  }

  if (redirect) {
    return <Navigate to={'/'} />
  }
  return (

    <form className="login" onSubmit={login}>
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <div className="form-container">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="username"
          value={username}
          onChange={ev => setUsername(ev.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="password"
          placeholder="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={ev => setPassword(ev.target.value)}
        />
        <div style={{ width: '400px' }}>
          <button className="btn ac_btn">Login</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Here's my Express backend code

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = require('./models/User');
const Post = require('./models/Post');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const app = express();
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const multer = require('multer');
const uploadMiddleware = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() });
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
require('dotenv').config();

const serviceAccount = {
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  clientEmail: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
  privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
};

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_BUCKET,
});

const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
const domain = 'https://personal-website-ea41b.web.app';

app.use(cors({
  origin: domain,
  credentials: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());

const uri = process.env.MONGO_URL;

mongoose.connect(uri, {
  serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 30000,
});

app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  try {
    const userDoc = await User.create({
      username,
      password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt),
    });
    res.json(userDoc);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(400).json(e);
  }
});

app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  const userDoc = await User.findOne({ username });
  const passOk = bcrypt.compareSync(password, userDoc.password);
  if (passOk) {
    jwt.sign({ username, id: userDoc._id }, secret, {}, (err, token) => {
      console.log('token-secret', secret, token)
      if (err) throw err;
      res.cookie('token', token).json({
        id: userDoc._id,
        username,
      });
    });
  } else {
    res.status(400).json('wrong credentials');
  }
});

app.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
  const { token } = req.cookies;
  console.log('profile token', token);
  jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, (err, info) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json(info);
  });
});

app.post('/logout', (req, res) => {
  res.cookie('token', '').json('ok');
});

app.post('/post', uploadMiddleware.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
  const { originalname } = req.file;
  const { title, summary, content } = req.body;

  const fileUpload = bucket
    .file(`blog_covers/` + originalname);

  const blobStream = fileUpload.createWriteStream({

    metadata: {
      contentType: req.file.mimetype,
    },
  });

  blobStream.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).json('Error uploading file');
  });

  blobStream.on('finish', async () => {
    const [url] = await fileUpload.getSignedUrl({
      action: 'read',
      expires: '03-01-2500',
    });

    const { token } = req.cookies;
    jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, async (err, info) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      const postDoc = await Post.create({
        title,
        summary,
        content,
        cover: url,
        author: info.id,
      });
      res.json(postDoc);
    });
  });

  blobStream.end(req.file.buffer);
});

app.put('/post', uploadMiddleware.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
  const { id, title, summary, content } = req.body;

  const postDoc = await Post.findById(id);
  const isAuthor = JSON.stringify(postDoc.author) === JSON.stringify(info.id);
  if (!isAuthor) {
    return res.status(400).json('you are not the author');
  }

  const fileUpload = bucket.file(req.file.originalname);

  const blobStream = fileUpload.createWriteStream({
    metadata: {
      contentType: req.file.mimetype,
    },
  });

  blobStream.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).json('Error uploading file');
  });

  blobStream.on('finish', async () => {
    const [url] = await fileUpload.getSignedUrl({
      action: 'read',
      expires: '03-01-2500',
    });

    const { token } = req.cookies;
    jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, async (err, decodedToken) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      await postDoc.update({
        title,
        summary,
        content,
        cover: url ? url : postDoc.cover,
      });
      res.json(postDoc);
    });
  });

  blobStream.end(req.file.buffer);
});

app.get('/post', async (req, res) => {
  res.json(
    await Post.find()
      .populate('author', ['username'])
      .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
      .limit(20)
  );
});

app.get('/post/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const postDoc = await Post.findById(id).populate('author', ['username']);
  res.json(postDoc);
});

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 4000');
});
```

When I try to log in, the response from the server is successful, but the token property is always undefined.

[image]

I've checked the server response.

[image]

I've tried using console.log to debug the issue, but I'm still unable to identify the root cause.

Could someone please help me understand why the token property is undefined and how to resolve this issue?

Comment: If you are using separate backend and frontend. You can't really set the token from backend.
Return the token itself from the api response and then use `js-cookie` or any other cookie handler pacakge to set in the frontend from the login success response

Comment: I did as you said at frontend, getting token at frontend but still in backend it's still having same issue

Comment: `async function createNewPost(ev) {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.set('title', title);
    data.set('summary', summary);
    data.set('content', content);
    data.set('file', files[0]);
    ev.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch('https://personal-website-on6a.onrender.com/post', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${userToken}`,
        'Content-type':'application/json'
      },
    })
    if (response.ok) {
      setRedirect(true);
    }
  }`
How to send token?